# Write MYSQL query to CSV file can't write query

Tags: php, mysql, csv

All of this resides on an ubuntu LAMP server. I am trying to put the results of a sql query into a csv file. The php can query the db and create the csv file. But I can't get it to write the results to the csv file.

```
 <?php
//connect to db and query
$db_conn=mysqli_connect(xxxx, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($db_conn))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn,'SELECT time, bid, ask, volume FROM MtGox LIMIT 50');
$fp = fopen('/var/www/BTCData.csv',"w")or die("can't open file");

//store results as array and put into csv file
$fp = fopen('/var/www/TempFile.csv',"w")or die("can't open file");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)or die('failure!');
foreach ($row as $fields) {
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
echo 'success!';
?>
```

Comment: You should put your `mysqli_fetch_assoc` call inmto a loop, too, or you'll only get a single row. Also - you're opening two CSV files; which one do you want to write to?

Comment: I want to write to BTCData. The problem seems to be getting the data from the mysqli_fetch_assoc. If I print or echo the results on the webpage all rows come out just fine. However, I can't get it in to the csv file. I can write to the directory because I have written dummy text to some text files just to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_conn=mysqli_connect(xxxx, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($db_conn)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn,'SELECT time, bid, ask, volume FROM MtGox LIMIT 50');   
$data = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data .= $row['time'].';';
    $data .= $row['bid'].';';
    $data .= $row['ask'].';';
    $data .= $row['volume'].';';
}

file_put_contents ('/var/www/BTCData.csv', $data);
```

Comment: This creates the csv file but does not write anything to it.